# How to track head using Kinect

Tags: xna, kinect

I want to track the head of a player in order to move the camera inside XNA.
When the player rotates left or right, the camera inside XNA will respond to this action and will also rotate.

I tried using the head joint from Skeleton Data and taking the vector value X,Y but this is not an accurate solution. I need another solution that can rotate the camera inside XNA.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean tracking if the player's head is turning left or right? Since probably there is no large variation for the depth values in this case you could probably use the color info and track position of the eyes for example. I think there is an example of face tracking in the new MS SDK (1.5) also.

Comment: I'am intend to build FPS game that take the playe's movement using kinect SDK 1 Kinect for Xbox36,not the kinect SDK1.5 ,so when the player move the camera position inside xna will move corresponding to this movement

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [Face Tracking API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx) and see the difference from a certain point on the users face (like their nose) to decide whether or not the user looked in a different direction. The points on a users face are assembled like this:

[image: stuff]

Then you can see if the X changed and by what amount to see the rotation effects.
(You might want to see [Facial Recognition with Kinect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263501/facial-recognition-with-kinect))

Comment: Facial Recognition is just support for sdk 1.5 and i'm using sdk 1.0 for xbox device not  windows sensor

Comment: @user I use an xbox kinect with face tracking and version 1.5, you should update

Comment: Just ask if you need more help